# Getting error message in grey"Failed to get available update data" while updating modules version.How to update now

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

Updating the Drupal version to latest from 7.34, but Getting the error message everytime "Failed to get available update data" .So not able to update .tried various things clearing cache tables from database from and all increasing execution time and all, but does'nt worked . Help please

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this for the past couple of hours, too. The update approach I've used was through `drush pm-update` which attempts to update everything to the latest available version.

I think core and/or other modules are being updated though when verifying the admin interface you get **Failed to get available update data for X projects** error message.

For me, running `drush pm-update -v` displays the following results:

```
vagrant@localhost:/var/www/web$ drush pm-update -v
Initialized Drupal 7.41 root directory at /opt/web                                                                                                                                [notice]
Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default                                                                                                                                  [notice]
Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_TwuPwr --database=dbname --host=localhost --silent  < /tmp/drush_c6bIwC
Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_tzSPy5 --database=dbname --host=localhost --silent  < /tmp/drush_CiqLxg
Loading release_info engine.                                                                                                                                                      [notice]
Loading version_control engine.                                                                                                                                                   [notice]
Loading package_handler engine.                                                                                                                                                   [notice]
Executing: wget --version
Loading update_status engine.                                                                                                                                                     [notice]
/usr/bin/php /home/vagrant/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php --php=/usr/bin/php  --backend=2 --verbose --root=/opt/web --uri=http://default  pm-updatestatus 2>&1            [notice]
Update information last refreshed: 27 Oct
 Name                                             Installed Version  Proposed version  Message    
 Better Exposed Filters (better_exposed_filters)  7.x-3.2            7.x-3.2           Up to date 
 Date (date)                                      7.x-2.9            7.x-2.9           Up to date 
 Devel (devel)                                    7.x-1.5            7.x-1.5           Up to date 
 Display Suite (ds)                               7.x-2.11           7.x-2.11          Up to date 
 Entity Reference (entityreference)               7.x-1.1            7.x-1.1           Up to date 
 features_extra                                   7.x-1.0            7.x-1.0           Up to date 
 Field collection (field_collection)              7.x-1.0-beta10     7.x-1.0-beta10    Up to date 
 jQuery Update (jquery_update)                    7.x-3.0-alpha3     7.x-3.0-alpha3    Up to date 
 MultiBlock (multiblock)                          7.x-1.4            7.x-1.4           Up to date 
 Reg With Pic (reg_with_pic)                      7.x-1.0            7.x-1.0           Up to date 
 Search pages (search_api_page)                   7.x-1.2            7.x-1.2           Up to date 
 Solr search (search_api_solr)                    7.x-1.9            7.x-1.9           Up to date 
 simplehtmldom API (simplehtmldom)                7.x-1.12           7.x-1.12          Up to date 


No code updates available.                                                                                                                                                     [ok]
Command dispatch complete                                                                                                                                                         [notice]
Command dispatch complete                                                                                                                                                         [notice]
```

Running `drush pm-updatestatus -v` provides extra details regarding update data:

```
vagrant@localhost:/var/www/web$ drush pm-updatestatus -v
Initialized Drupal 7.41 root directory at /opt/web                                                                                                                                [notice]
Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default                                                                                                                                  [notice]
Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_V95fLt --database=dbname --host=localhost --silent  < /tmp/drush_R3mRJd
Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_EX6oPZ --database=dbname --host=localhost --silent  < /tmp/drush_rlKjNJ
Loading outputformat engine.                                                                                                                                                      [notice]
Loading update_status engine.                                                                                                                                                     [notice]
Checking available update data ...                                                                                                                                             [ok]
Checking available update data for Drupal.                                                                                                                                     [ok]
Downloading release history from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/drupal/7.x                                                                                            [notice]
Executing: wget --version
Executing: wget -q --timeout=30 -O /tmp/download_file8oKYNz https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/drupal/7.x
simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "" Project.php:72                                                                                          [warning]
Failed to get available update data from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/drupal/7.x                                                                                 [error]
Checking available update data for Better Exposed Filters (better_exposed_filters).                                                                                            [ok]
Downloading release history from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/better_exposed_filters/7.x                                                                            [notice]
/home/vagrant/.drush/cache/download/https---updates.drupal.org-release-history-better_exposed_filters-7.x retrieved from cache.                                                   [notice]
Checking available update data for Chaos tools (ctools).                                                                                                                       [ok]
Downloading release history from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/ctools/7.x                                                                                            [notice]
Executing: wget -q --timeout=30 -O /tmp/download_file6oSaWv https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/ctools/7.x
simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "" Project.php:72                                                                                          [warning]
Failed to get available update data from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/ctools/7.x                                                                                 [error]
Checking available update data for Facet API (facetapi).                                                                                                                       [ok]
Downloading release history from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/facetapi/7.x                                                                                          [notice]
Executing: wget -q --timeout=30 -O /tmp/download_fileHuM94a https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/facetapi/7.x
simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "" Project.php:72                                                                                          [warning]
Failed to get available update data from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/facetapi/7.x                                                                               [error]
Checking available update data for Date (date).                                                                                                                                [ok]
Downloading release history from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/date/7.x                                                                                              [notice]
/home/vagrant/.drush/cache/download/https---updates.drupal.org-release-history-date-7.x retrieved from cache.                                                                     [notice]
Checking available update data for Devel (devel).                                                                                                                              [ok]
Downloading release history from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/devel/7.x                                                                                             [notice]
/home/vagrant/.drush/cache/download/https---updates.drupal.org-release-history-devel-7.x retrieved from cache.                                                                    [notice]
Checking available update data for Diff (diff).                                                                                                                                [ok]
Downloading release history from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/diff/7.x                                                                                              [notice]
Executing: wget -q --timeout=30 -O /tmp/download_fileZvaTnA https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/diff/7.x
simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "" Project.php:72                                                                                          [warning]
Failed to get available update data from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/diff/7.x                                                                                   [error]
Checking available update data for Display Suite (ds).                                                                                                                         [ok]
Downloading release history from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/ds/7.x                                                                                                [notice]
/home/vagrant/.drush/cache/download/https---updates.drupal.org-release-history-ds-7.x retrieved from cache.                                                                       [notice]
Checking available update data for Entity API (entity).                                                                                                                        [ok]
Downloading release history from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/entity/7.x                                                                                            [notice]
Executing: wget -q --timeout=30 -O /tmp/download_filenmNtZH https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/entity/7.x
simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "" Project.php:72                                                                                          [warning]
Failed to get available update data from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/entity/7.x                                                                                 [error]
Checking available update data for Entity Reference (entityreference).                                                                                                         [ok]
Downloading release history from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/entityreference/7.x                                                                                   [notice]
/home/vagrant/.drush/cache/download/https---updates.drupal.org-release-history-entityreference-7.x retrieved from cache.                                                          [notice]
Checking available update data for features_extra.                                                                                                                             [ok]
Downloading release history from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/features_extra/7.x                                                                                    [notice]
/home/vagrant/.drush/cache/download/https---updates.drupal.org-release-history-features_extra-7.x retrieved from cache.                                                           [notice]
Checking available update data for Features (features).                                                                                                                        [ok]
Downloading release history from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/features/7.x                                                                                          [notice]
Executing: wget -q --timeout=30 -O /tmp/download_fileVcZnYa https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/features/7.x
simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "" Project.php:72                                                                                          [warning]
Failed to get available update data from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/features/7.x                                                                               [error]
Checking available update data for Field collection (field_collection).                                                                                                        [ok]
Downloading release history from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/field_collection/7.x                                                                                  [notice]
/home/vagrant/.drush/cache/download/https---updates.drupal.org-release-history-field_collection-7.x retrieved from cache.                                                         [notice]
Checking available update data for jQuery Update (jquery_update).                                                                                                              [ok]
Downloading release history from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/jquery_update/7.x                                                                                     [notice]
/home/vagrant/.drush/cache/download/https---updates.drupal.org-release-history-jquery_update-7.x retrieved from cache.                                                            [notice]
Checking available update data for Module filter (module_filter).                                                                                                              [ok]
Downloading release history from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/module_filter/7.x                                                                                     [notice]
Executing: wget -q --timeout=30 -O /tmp/download_file2k1kpX https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/module_filter/7.x
simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "" Project.php:72                                                                                          [warning]
Failed to get available update data from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/module_filter/7.x                                                                          [error]
Checking available update data for MultiBlock (multiblock).                                                                                                                    [ok]
Downloading release history from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/multiblock/7.x                                                                                        [notice]
/home/vagrant/.drush/cache/download/https---updates.drupal.org-release-history-multiblock-7.x retrieved from cache.                                                               [notice]
Checking available update data for Reg With Pic (reg_with_pic).                                                                                                                [ok]
Downloading release history from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/reg_with_pic/7.x                                                                                      [notice]
/home/vagrant/.drush/cache/download/https---updates.drupal.org-release-history-reg_with_pic-7.x retrieved from cache.                                                             [notice]
Checking available update data for Search API (search_api).                                                                                                                    [ok]
Downloading release history from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/search_api/7.x                                                                                        [notice]
Executing: wget -q --timeout=30 -O /tmp/download_fileveChtP https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/search_api/7.x
simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "" Project.php:72                                                                                          [warning]
Failed to get available update data from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/search_api/7.x                                                                             [error]
Checking available update data for Search API attachments (search_api_attachments).                                                                                            [ok]
Downloading release history from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/search_api_attachments/7.x                                                                            [notice]
Executing: wget -q --timeout=30 -O /tmp/download_fileQZQIGN https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/search_api_attachments/7.x
simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "" Project.php:72                                                                                          [warning]
Failed to get available update data from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/search_api_attachments/7.x                                                                 [error]
Checking available update data for Search pages (search_api_page).                                                                                                             [ok]
Downloading release history from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/search_api_page/7.x                                                                                   [notice]
/home/vagrant/.drush/cache/download/https---updates.drupal.org-release-history-search_api_page-7.x retrieved from cache.                                                          [notice]
Checking available update data for Solr search (search_api_solr).                                                                                                              [ok]
Downloading release history from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/search_api_solr/7.x                                                                                   [notice]
/home/vagrant/.drush/cache/download/https---updates.drupal.org-release-history-search_api_solr-7.x retrieved from cache.                                                          [notice]
Checking available update data for simplehtmldom API (simplehtmldom).                                                                                                          [ok]
Downloading release history from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/simplehtmldom/7.x                                                                                     [notice]
/home/vagrant/.drush/cache/download/https---updates.drupal.org-release-history-simplehtmldom-7.x retrieved from cache.                                                            [notice]
Checking available update data for Views (views).                                                                                                                              [ok]
Downloading release history from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/views/7.x                                                                                             [notice]
Executing: wget -q --timeout=30 -O /tmp/download_fileH8g7Uo https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/views/7.x
simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "" Project.php:72                                                                                          [warning]
Failed to get available update data from https://updates.drupal.org/release-history/views/7.x                                                                                  [error]
 Name                                             Installed Version  Proposed version  Message    
 Better Exposed Filters (better_exposed_filters)  7.x-3.2            7.x-3.2           Up to date 
 Date (date)                                      7.x-2.9            7.x-2.9           Up to date 
 Devel (devel)                                    7.x-1.5            7.x-1.5           Up to date 
 Display Suite (ds)                               7.x-2.11           7.x-2.11          Up to date 
 Entity Reference (entityreference)               7.x-1.1            7.x-1.1           Up to date 
 features_extra                                   7.x-1.0            7.x-1.0           Up to date 
 Field collection (field_collection)              7.x-1.0-beta10     7.x-1.0-beta10    Up to date 
 jQuery Update (jquery_update)                    7.x-3.0-alpha3     7.x-3.0-alpha3    Up to date 
 MultiBlock (multiblock)                          7.x-1.4            7.x-1.4           Up to date 
 Reg With Pic (reg_with_pic)                      7.x-1.0            7.x-1.0           Up to date 
 Search pages (search_api_page)                   7.x-1.2            7.x-1.2           Up to date 
 Solr search (search_api_solr)                    7.x-1.9            7.x-1.9           Up to date 
 simplehtmldom API (simplehtmldom)                7.x-1.12           7.x-1.12          Up to date 

Command dispatch complete
```

from which I can see a lot of `simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "" Project.php:72` errors.

**Later edit**
Rerunning `drush pm-updatestatus -v` after 5 minutes displayed lots of **[ok]** instead of the **[error]**s or **[warning]**s above. Verifying the admin also displayed a positive message: **Checked available update data for X projects**.

So in the end I think this is an update details availability issue.